# Trouble setting Attachments with C# MS Graph API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I've been kickin' at this all night, so I'm reaching out for help. I'm trying to forward an Outlook email message as an attachment. This is a .net6 console app using MS Graph.

```
    static void ProcessError(Message badmessage)
    {
        var newEmail = new Message
        {
            Subject = "A unfortunate circumstance has presented itself!",
            Body = new ItemBody { ContentType = BodyType.Text, Content = "The attached Outlook item was bad."},
            ToRecipients = new List<Recipient>{ new Recipient { EmailAddress = new EmailAddress { Address = "me@you.com" } } },
            Attachments = new List<Attachment> { new Attachment { ODataType = "#microsoft.graph.itemAttachment" , Item = badmessage} }
        };
        
        graphClient.Users[sUserID].SendMail(newEmail, true).Request().PostAsync(); // This works (if you remove the attachment code)
    }
```

I'm following examples I've found on the net and in ChatGPT, and see multiple references using the code starting with "Attachments = ..." above. But no matter how I come at it I get these two errors:

```
CS0122  'Attachment.Attachment()' is inaccessible due to its protection level    
CS0117  'Attachment' does not contain a definition for 'Item'
```

The code samples I found don't compile, so I must be missing something.

Answer (score 0):

`Attachment` is a base class. You need to use derived type `ItemAttachment`([code](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet/blob/support/4.x/src/Microsoft.Graph/Generated/model/ItemAttachment.cs))

```
static void ProcessError(Message badmessage)
{
    var newEmail = new Message
    {
        Subject = "A unfortunate circumstance has presented itself!",
        Body = new ItemBody { ContentType = BodyType.Text, Content = "The attached Outlook item was bad."},
        ToRecipients = new List<Recipient>{ new Recipient { EmailAddress = new EmailAddress { Address = "me@you.com" } } },
        Attachments = new List<Attachment> { new ItemAttachment { Item = badmessage } }
    };
    
    graphClient.Users[sUserID].SendMail(newEmail, true).Request().PostAsync();
}
```